# Do we need to include an escape character for slash (/) in search value in Solr Search

Tags: solr

Do we need to include an escape character for slash (/) in search value in Solr Search

```
q=*:*&indent=on&wt=json&rows=0&json.facet={"log_timestamp":{"type":"query","numBuckets":false,"facet":{"log_timestamp":{"type":"terms","field":"log_timestamp","limit":5,"mincount":1,"sort":{"count":"desc"},"numBuckets":true}},"q":"log_timestamp:/.*[AA][/][Cc].*/"},"destination_code_desc":{"type":"query","numBuckets":false,"facet":{"destination_code_desc":{"type":"terms","field":"destination_code_desc","limit":5,"mincount":1,"sort":{"count":"desc"},"numBuckets":true}},"q":"destination_code_desc:/.*[AA][/][Cc].*/"}}&fq=record_type:TEST&fq=log_timestamp:[1201-12-04T05:50:35Z+TO+2017-01-01T06:00:00Z]
```

Here is the error that I see

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.parser.TokenMgrError"],
    "msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'log_timestamp:/.*[AA][/][Cc].*/': Lexical error at line 1, column 24.  Encountered: \"]\" (93), after : \"\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: The double slash worked (\\\). I had tried earlier single slash and it didnot work. Thanks for your suggestion. I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to escape it - your issue is that you're searching by using a regular expression, and since you're using `/` as the delimiter of your expression, the `/` inside the expression ends the expression.

You can escape characters by putting `\` in front of them - but you may have to escape it twice if it doesn't work by itself, effectively putting in `\\/`. Try both.